# How to maintain a FIWARE apikey?

Tags: fiware, fiware-orion

Reviewing the [IoT Agent documentation](https://ngsi-ld-tutorials.readthedocs.io/en/latest/iot-agent.html#update-a-service-group) I have seen that the "apikey" is a parameter to uniquely identify a service group. The following figure shows how to identify a set of commands and attributes associated with a device type.

[image]

```
"services": [
        {
            "apikey": "5jggokgpepnvsb2uv4s40d59ov",
            "cbroker":     "'"http://orion:$ORION_PORT"'",
            "entity_type": "Agv",
            "transport": "MQTT",
            "resource": "",
            "commands": [
                {
          ....
```

However, I have not found information on whether there is any service that allows to create, verify and maintain the created apikey beyond managing them using a CRUD. Is there any FIWARE service or best practice that allows this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure what kind of managing service are you thinking on...

For example we've got an administration portal able to generate ramdom apikeys to be used and shared, we also use it to list and manage apikeys but they are kept just within the iotAgent Service and managed by using IotAgent api. We don't require an extra service, except some secret/password manager like Vaultier for ops purposes.

As part of the process we also share private integration docs for every data provider stating which apikeys they should use for every kind of device/measure. But there is no service involved. It's just an OTT process.

As for best practices:

- we append some "mark" or meaningful information within the apikey, so we can recognize them easily: **preMOBA**dfjf3ddfvDfj34f, **proDL**d3324jf3vDfj34f
- and we use 25 chars apikeys

Best

Comment: Your answer is exactly in line with what I was looking for. Thank you. Does this administration portal belong to the Fiware Stack? Does this administration portal also help you with the creation of new services, and devices on the fly?

Comment: It helps with the creation of new devices, groups of devices, services, subservices, entities, rules, subscriptions, users... It's 100% built upon FIWARE APIS (you can do everything he does by using APIS)... BUT it's not open source, Its part of our differential value in our platform solutions (Telefónica). BTW... devices may be created on the fly thanks to the IotAgent autoprovision capabilities.

Comment: Thanks again. Without deviating too much from the question, when you refer to IoTAgent's autoprovision capabilities, do you mean the fact that you can perform CRUD on top of IoTAgent?

Comment: You don’t need to provision/register every single device if you don’t want to. Just by defining a group of devices with the autoprovision flag, the devices themselves will get registered into the iotAgent when its first measure arrives.